# Railsinstaller with ruby 1.8.7

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

Can anyone tell me how to install rails in windows7 with ruby 1.8.7.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend installing a ruby version manager such as [pik](https://github.com/vertiginous/pik) to manage installing a sandboxed 1.8.7 - in particular, look at the readme on the github page for using a msi installer package to install ruby from scratch. A ruby version manager is incredibly handy to have, as it lets you flip back and forth between different rubies, with different installed gems, and, if this is important to you, can install various rubies without requiring admin privileges (to run the installer package for pik may require admin privileges).

From this point, use the standard Ruby tools like `gem` to install Rails. I recommend installing [bundler](http://gembundler.com/) with `gem install bundler`, then using bundler to handle the rest of your gem needs, as is detailed in the bundler link and especially [here](http://gembundler.com/rails3.html). Bundler is great because it manages your configuration precisely based on a file in the directory; this means multiple projects can have multiple versions of different libraries installed, but Bundler makes sure that the configuration is consitent for each project. You can even move your project (including your bundler Gemfile) to a different computer and run `bundle install` and it will ensure your other computer is using the exact same versions of the same gems for running your software - great for deployment.

Comment: Here in pik documentation they mentioned to change %USERPROFILE% in pik..But i didn understand that line.Can you please explain me